# React start and build gives heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I don't know why but when I want to start or build my react app it gives me heap out of memory.
I have added --max_old_space_size=8192 to my script but didn't help at all.
Error:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8192 build
Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run the following command: `npx browserslist --update-db`

<--- Last few GCs --->
 =[19708:000001E532E834F0]    67245 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2049.4 (2054.4) -> 2049.0 (2055.9) MB, 1394.8 / 0.0 ms  (+ 64.9 ms in 12 steps since start of marking, biggest step 10.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 1473 ms) (average mu = 0.090, current mu[19708:000001E532E834F0]    68633 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2050.1 (2054.9) -> 2049.2 (2056.1) MB, 1315.3 / 0.0 ms  (+ 58.6 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 5.4 ms, walltime since start of marking 1388 ms) (average mu = 0.051, current mu 

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6375C1DDF napi_wrap+109135
 2: 00007FF637566D06 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfElementsOffset+33350
 3: 00007FF637567AD6 node::OnFatalError+294
 4: 00007FF637E364CE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF637E1B31D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF637CC574C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF637CD0AAA v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
 8: 00007FF637CCDC59 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
 9: 00007FF637CC27F1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2033
10: 00007FF637CC09F5 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1365
11: 00007FF637CE3041 v8::internal::Factory::NewJSArrayWithUnverifiedElements+305
12: 00007FF637CE2EEF v8::internal::Factory::NewJSArrayWithElements+31
13: 00007FF6379E27F0 v8::internal::DeclarationScope::was_lazily_parsed+4608
14: 00007FF6379E6626 v8::sampler::Sampler::IsActive+4934
15: 00007FF637EBF01D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+463949
16: 00007FF637F0EBFA v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+790570
17: 00007FF637EAFE12 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+401986
18: 0000032CD31E57A5
Done in 75.13s.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this problem because of large files in my project.

writing below line in .env file solve my problem.

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

or you can also try:

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
"winBuild": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build",
```